# Python pandas drop_duplicates inserts unnecessary " which lead to csv loading error

Tags: python, pandas, csv, drop-duplicates

in my project I am loading every other day data from Twitter an append it to a csv file. This procedure leads to exact duplicates of tweets in my csv file. That's why I want to remove these exact duplicates.

However, when I run the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("Hashtags.csv", engine="python")

data.drop_duplicates(subset=None, inplace=True)
data.to_csv("Hashtags.csv",index = False)
```

and then try to load the csv file I get the following error

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: ',' expected after '"'
```

Before I dropped the duplicates I had no problems with loading the file. It seems almost like the drop_duplicates function inserts unnecessary " signs. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If you are getting this error while loading csv as you said then it should not be related with `drop_duplicates`. Is this still working when you remove the `drop_dupilcates` line?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55010807/pandas-errors-parsererror-expected-after/56690122

Comment: I think ParserError is from `read_csv`

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why it works now. But I changed the code on how I save the pandas Dataframe to a csv.file and now it works.

```
fname = 'Hashtags'
data.drop_duplicates(subset=None, inplace=True)

with open('%s.csv' % fname, 'w', encoding="utf8") as file:
    data.to_csv(file,index = False)
```