# Read spark csv dataframe as pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

After processing a big data on pyspark, I saved it on csv using the following command:

```
df.repartition(1).write.option("header", "true").option("delimeter", "\t").csv("csv_data", mode="overwrite")
```

Now, I want use `pd.read_csv()` to load it again.

```
info = pd.read_csv('part0000.csv', sep='\t', header='infer')
```

`info` is returned as 1 column where the data is separated by comma not '\t'.

```
col1name,col2name,col3name
val1,val2,val3
```

I tried to specify the `sep=','` but I got an parsing error where some rows have more than 3 cols.

How to fix that without skipping any rows ? Is there anything to do with spark to resolve it such as specify a `'|'` as delimiter

Answer (score 0):

The csv format writer method **DOESN'T** have the `delimeter` option, guess what you need is the `sep` option.

Please refer to [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html#data-source-option)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66236942/2130515),  `pandas` treats the char `"` for queting, and expects `"` after every `"` which is not always true in my case. To fix this problem, we have to specify `quoting=3` to not use quote.

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header='infer', sep='\t', engine='python', quoting=3)
```