# ParserError: ' ' expected after '"' in python pandas/dask

Tags: python, pandas, dask

Hi I'm using 3GB txt file and want to change it to CSV but it gives error_bad_lines

```
ParserError: '  ' expected after '"'
```

Code I am using

```
df1 = df.read_csv("path\\logs.txt", delimiter = "\t", encoding = 'cp437',engine="python")
df1.to_csv("C:\\Data\\log1.csv",quotechar='"',error_bad_lines=False, header=None, on_bad_lines='skip')
```

Comment: Don’t post the original file, but debug down to a few lines that caused the problem and post those

Comment: You may need to pre-process the file - as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55010807/pandas-errors-parsererror-expected-after

Comment: Would it be possible to provide maybe the first 5 rows of the csv file - to see what you are dealing with ?

Comment: Hi Scot, I would love to provide you the complete file only, as I am new here, I can not paste here, its too big single row only consist 2000 letter, any way how to send it to you

Comment: Use the option `nrows=...` incrementally to find out which row causes the problem. Inspect or post that row.

Comment: @DYZ, thanks.. can you please tell me the command, is it like nrows=2000, but file is so large, having 3-4 millions rows

Comment: So what? Keep searching until you find the offending row. That's the way.

Comment: can you please tell me what it mean: ParserError: ' ' expected after '"' !!! is it like I have some "space" in any column just after "double quotes"?

Comment: I have updated my answer to help you get this issue fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The following code  locates **unwanted** quotation marks (`'` and `"`) between each record or tab, and replaces it with `nothing`.
It then replaces the tab (`\t`) with a comma (`,`).

This script uses [`regex`](https://regex101.com/r/7d4VsN/1) to locate the unwanted quotation marks.

```py
import re

# Use regex to locate unwanted quotation marks
pattern = re.compile(r"(?!^|\"$)[\"\']")

new_file = open("C:\\Data\\log1.csv", "a")

# Read the file
with open("path\\logs.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        new_l = ""
        for l in line.split('\t'):
            
            # Replace the unwanted quotation marks
            l = re.sub(pattern, "", l)
            if new_l == "":
                new_l = new_l + l
            else:
                new_l = new_l + ',' + l
        
        # Write the line to the new file        
        new_file.write(new_l)

new_file.close()
```

The reason you are seeing the issue that you are seeing, is that you have an unwanted quotation mark within the record. For example:

```
"The"\t"quick brown"" fox "jumps over the"\t"lazy dog"
```

Comment: do you mean I have to use single slash ("\") instead of double? this also doesn't work

Comment: Thanks a lot @Scott for helping, I'm using the same code which you suggested but still same error:    ParserError: ' ' expected after '"',     I guess there should be some problem with my input file but its so big I can not even open it manually

Comment: I have updated my answer @PrashantSharma - this should hopefully work now,

Answer (score 0):

Add on_bad_lines=‘warn’ to your read_csv. Looks like there is some wrong line.

Comment: Thanks Kallaghaan.. but , I used both "warn" , "skip" but still it didn't work. Again its showing this error: ParserError: ' ' expected after '"'